# Eslint rule: validate blanks in a variable declaration

Tags: eslint

Validate this statement: (space between the variable, the = and the string)

**wrong**

`let mystring="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."`

**good**

`let mystring = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."`

I've been looking for a rule to validate that in the documentation but I can't find anything about it

**UPDATE**
The rule to validate this is:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops

Comment: What is that you exactly need check if there is space in your string ?

Comment: space between the variable, the = and the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [prettier](https://prettier.io/) for code formatting and code beautify. This is very helpful. You can read the documentation and get to know its features. You can use in IDE as well as in the build.

Comment: I already had a solution using prettier, but I want to do it using eslint